# Missing Window Switcher and Expo not working

Tags: unity, compiz

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 (64 bit). Unfortunately it seems that my favourite window switcher in Compiz is missing in 13.04?

Does anyone know if:

1. this is a bug.
2. there is a way to get it back (maybe a plugin)
3. this is because I used the software center to install compiz which results in an out of date version?

Also, the shortcut to trigger the expo is super-s, however this only works sometimes, such as after a reboot. Right now, I am having to manually click this icon to have the same effect.

[image]

Is there a way I can just map that icon to the keyboad shortcuts (workaround)?

Also, the 'commands' feature appears to be missing from compiz as well (it used to be by 'general'. This is 'ok' as I have managed to set everything from the normal keyboard shortcuts menu for now as shown here:
[image]

Summary:

1. How can I install the compiz window switcher in ubuntu 13.04.
2. How do I get the 'expo' feature to always trigger when I press cntrl-s

---

Update:

It appears that disabling the launcher key (super) also disables the expo functionality (super-s). Is there any way to disable the launcher without disabling the 'expo' functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absence of workspace switcher is not a bug, but a design decision. To reenable it, simply right click on your desktop and choose `Change Desktop Background`. Then hit the `Behavior` tab and enable the workspace switcher.

[image]

As for the keyboard shortcuts to open the Dash and Expo, these can be simply changed in the CompizConfig Settings Manager.
For the Dash, click on `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`, then change the shortcut at the top:

[image]

For Expo, click on `Expo` and change the `Expo key` shortcut:

[image]

Finally, as rrosa pointed out, you need to make sure you have installed the extra Compiz plugins to use `Commands` in the CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Answer (score 0):

i did this and got the switchers back:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra compiz-plugins compiz-gnome
```

salú